# Hijacking DOM manipulations

Tags: javascript, dom, audio

I have a problem. I am trying to get the source of an audio element as soon as it changes and without making it connect to the server. Let me elaborate: The server allows only one request (randomly generated url for content), which I am trying to get and obviously I don't want the audio element to reload using a new source. I am currently using a mutation observer, but with no luck of beating the `onclick`'s speed (yes, there's complicated js involved in order to not allow anybody to get the source directly). Here's the code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].setAttribute("autoplay", false);
//not sure if ^^ makes a difference
audioObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    window.open(mutations[0].target.src);
    //I only listen for one mutation and want to open the url in a new window
    audioObserver.disconnect();
    //don't listen in order to not cause infinite loop
    document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]);
    //remove the element in order to avoid reloading
});
observerConfig = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: false,
    characterData: false
};
audioObserver.observe(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0], observerConfig);
```

I would be happy with any implementation i.e. not necessarily MutationObserver. Is there anyway to literally hijack the attribute change?

Comment: @dave how does that solve the audio reloading problem? I find using setTimeout too CPU-intensive and this seems like a task that can be done through other methods.

Comment: Maybe you can overwrite the onclick function, but can´t give much help without example

Comment: @juvian overwrite to what :)? That function does all the magic in getting the URL, 'cause this is not a server-side controlled enviroment, only what is available in the client-side.

Comment: manipulating the `preload` attribute https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-media-preload might help solve this problem without any hijacking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that `MutationObserver` can't do what you need. The way those work, browsers collect mutation records while a script runs, then passes the records to the observers all at once when the script yields. It's pretty much asynchronous. This is what makes mutation *observers* perform better than mutation *events*, which are dispatched synchronously. By the time the observer runs, the `audio` element will have received the URL and have started loading it.

---

Supposing that this `onclick` handler you're talking about sets the element's `.src` property, you'll want to define a custom setter for that, so that you can intercept the value before the `audio` element's implementation handles it.

You can define a setter like this in JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/omqdx8d1/

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
Object.defineProperty(el, 'src', {
    set: function (newSrc) {
        console.log('they set src to ' + newSrc);
    }
});
```

In Chrome, this will make it impossible to call the original setter afterward, but it sounds like you're not worried about that.

---

Another way to modify an element's attributes is to use the `setAttribute` method. If you want to intercept this, you can redefine the element's `setAttribute` method.

Here's another example that uses `setAttribute`: http://jsfiddle.net/5mLysc9n/1/

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
var origSetAttribute = el.setAttribute;
el.setAttribute = function (name, value) {
    console.log('they set ' + name + ' to ' + value);
    // origSetAttribute.call(el, name, value);
};
```

When you monkey patch a method, you can save the original method function, which can be useful.

Comment: I'll try this and mark it as an answer ASAP. BTW I've checked the audio element, it does have a preload attribute, I'll disable that as well.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work, it just returned the audio element, however the jsfiddle example seems to work. One more thing: the handler does change the src property, since the MutationObserver object does have an attribute log (when I tried it it showed the src attribute).

Comment: I even tried to delete it and then create another audio tag in the same div, still doesn't work :(

Comment: In firefox I get: 
TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property 'src'

Comment: Even if I set it to configurable, still nothing happens (at least no error in ff).

Comment: I added info on intercepting another way applications can change the `src`.